# Classic ASP: Tools for tracing includes?

Tags: asp-classic, include, dependencies

Are there any tools that will analyze an asp application and identify the dependencies?  I've tried to do it by hand, but there are some includes nested 2-3 levels deep.

If that's not possible, is there any way to configure the runtime somehow to log include processing?

Comment: I don't know any but I would just like to wish you good luck.

Comment: Thanks.  I find the most useful tool for this type of situation is often a bottle of good scotch.

Comment: Why not put a piece of logging code in each include? As the commenters have pointed out already there's no out-of-the-box solution for this, but you can log all the include calls by adding a piece of logging logic to each one. It's not pretty but it works.

Answer (score 1):

When you debug it in Visual Studion, you can see the whole tree of includes in the Solution Browser window.

Comment: This shows as "Script Documents" under the solution in Solution Explorer. Note that it didn't show for me when hitting the page in Chrome, I had to first open it in Edge then it appeared and I could go back to using chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the simplest solution, but you may want to look at the [ASP Profiler](http://aspprofiler.sourceforge.net/). Among other things, it shows the sum total code that goes to the interpreter - including all the includes.

As far as I know, there's no in-your-face answer as to what has been included, but you can figure it out in fairly short order.

The only downside is that you cannot use it to profile pages that only accept data via POST (unless I missed something). You can still create an intermediate file for those pages. Add a small, easy to search for, comment a the top of your includes (assuming there isn't one already) and you could use that to do a quick-n-dirty search/assessment.

Again, not the most simple, straight forward solution - but it cuts down on a chunk of the hassle.